# Why these methods return a Rational and Integer for the same operation

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to figure out why one approach returns a `Rational` whilst the other method peforming the same operation returns an `Integer`.

My best guess is that Ruby is unable to switch from Fixnum to Bignum!?

```rb
(1..64).to_a.map.with_index { |_v, i| 2**(i - 1) }.sum.class #Rational
(1..64).inject { |total,n| total + 2**(n-1)}.class           #Integer
```

I would have expected both approaches to return an Integer. I am using the `inject` version if anyone is asking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first index of the method with_index, by default, is 0. Therefore, your functions yield different values. As example, check the first value generated on the first function:

```
2**(i - 1) = 2 ** -1 = 1/2
```

Notice the rational here?

**This affects the overall math, making the two values differ from one another.**

You need to pass the arg "1" to with_index.

```
(1..64).to_a.map.with_index(1) { |_v, i| 2**(i - 1) }.sum == (1..64).inject { |total,n| total + 2**(n-1)} 
=> true
```

Comment: spot on! forgot completely about with_index(1)! thanks

Comment: Good answer to a good question! It's perhaps worth noting that if `(i-1)` had been `(i-2)` a float would have been returned. You might provide the link [Integer#**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-2A-2A).